# How can I cache data in android?

Tags: android, caching

I've created a simple Messenger in android. Now I wanna cache user data and chat log for offline work. How can I do that??

I also use EasySave lib to implement that.

Comment: Use database for the cache is not cheap, better use shared preferences for caching your data.You can implement a class for cache data or use a library full feature for a cache like https://github.com/alirezat775/kesho

Answer (score 0):

try to use Room library for caching
https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/room.html